# Were the contributors to "The SEA is Ours" all already established authors?

Tags: short-stories, the-sea-is-ours

*The SEA is Ours* is an anthology collection of steampunk stories by various South-East Asian authors, including names such as Olivia Ho, Marilag Angway, and Timothy Dimacali. I know very little about either steampunk or South-East Asian literature, so none of these names were familiar to me; however, a little online searching told me that at least some of them, such as [Dimacali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TJ_Dimacali), were already well-known authors in the genre, and presumably were asked to contribute for that reason.

**Were all of the contributors already established authors?** In other words, is *The SEA is Ours* a collection of short stories by famous authors, the sort of anthology that might advertise itself by "includes stories from So-and-so!" - or is it a collaborative effort to create a new thing, a South-East Asian steampunk collection, by a mixed team qualified more by enthusiasm than experience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The SEA is Ours* [features a combination](http://rosariumpublishing.com/the-sea-is-ours.html) of widely established authors, experienced authors who are not yet widely known outside a particular niche audience, and authors who are just beginning to be published. This is unsurprising; it's typical of anthology collections to use Big Name contributors to boost awareness of unrecognized talent.

- [Marilag Angway](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/6981308.Marilag_Angway) has anthologized stories across several genres.
- [Paolo Chikiamco](http://www.salimbalcomics.com/creators) is writer and editor of many comics and anthologies, as well as interactive fiction works.
- [Timothy James M. Dimacali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TJ_Dimacali) writes both science fiction and science journalism. His work is studied in Philippine schools.
- [L.L. Hill](http://www.lauraleehill.com/)'s stories and poetry have been anthologized, and her entry for *The SEA is Ours* is an elaboration on a previous work.
- [Alessa Hinlo](http://www.alessahinlo.com/) is a newer writer; *The SEA is Ours* appears to be her second published short story.
- [Olivia Ho](http://silver-goggles.blogspot.com/2015/02/the-sea-is-ours-roundtable-olivia-ho_8.html) may be newly published, or I may just be bad at Googling.
- Robert Liow is published in the *Singapore Poetry Writing Month* anthology and by the Singapore’s Creative Arts Programme, but I think *The SEA is Ours* is his first international distribution.
- [Pear Nuallak](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/14813411.Pear_Nuallak) is published in a couple magazines.
- [Ivanna S. Mendels](https://twitter.com/wulfettenoire) writes short stories and children's books.
- [Kate Osias](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/5016187.Kate_Osias) is an award-winning author, and co-editor of volumes of the *Philippine Speculative Fiction*.
- [z.m. quỳnh](http://www.zmquynh.com/) writes short fiction, poetry, and non-fiction, but *The Sea is Ours* is her first speculative fiction work.
- [Nghi Vo](http://nghivo.com/wp/) is a professional author.

Obscurity and a small publishing portfolio don't equate to inexperience; many excellent and prolific authors never break out of their local region, and often an author's first work is a highly polished gem representing time and energy they'll never have the opportunity to again devote to a single work once they're immersed in the publishing grind.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.